# Calculating percentage changes (multi variables ) Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i asked about calculating percent change in my last question and gotten great help (thanks). However, when i tried to expand the variables, i start having problems.
Here's the original question with solution (thanks-'ansev')

Original question:
"I'm trying to get the % of fruit choice appearing on a specific day/month, like what's shown in the example.

I'm able to get total mean on the entire df with the following line. However, I'd like to view the changes in percentage through the days/months."

df:

```py
data = {'date':['1-Jan', '1-Feb', '1-Mar', '1-Apr', '1-May', '1-Jun', '1-July', '1-Aug', '1-Sep'], 'name':['john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'pete'], 'fruit':['apple', 'red', 'orange', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

soultion:

```py
df['values']=(df.groupby(['fruit','name']).cumcount()+1)/(df.groupby('name')['fruit'].cumcount()+1)
df2=df.pivot_table(index=df.index,columns='fruit',values='values').rename_axis(columns=None)
df2=df2.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(1-df2.sum(axis=1)) )*100
new_df=pd.concat([df.drop('values',axis=1),df2],axis=1)
```

output:

```
date    name        fruit   apple   orange
0   1-Jan   john    apple   100.000000  0.000000
1   1-Feb   john    apple   100.000000  0.000000
2   1-Mar   john    orange  66.666667   33.333333
3   1-Apr   john    apple   75.000000   25.000000
4   1-May   john    orange  60.000000   40.000000
5   1-Jun   john    orange  50.000000   50.000000
6   1-July  john    apple   57.142857   42.857143
7   1-Aug   john    apple   62.500000   37.500000
8   1-Sep   pete    orange  0.000000    100.000000
```

However, when i added more variables(fruits(mango)) into the data, i got this (on 1-Mar, it included mango, which shouldn't be included till 1-Apr:

```
date        name    fruit   apple       mango       orange
0   1-Jan   john    apple   100.000000  0.000000    0.000000
1   1-Feb   john    apple   100.000000  0.000000    0.000000
2   1-Mar   john    orange  33.333333   33.333333   33.333333
3   1-Apr   john    mango   37.500000   25.000000   37.500000
4   1-May   john    orange  30.000000   30.000000   40.000000
5   1-Jun   john    orange  25.000000   25.000000   50.000000
6   1-July  john    apple   42.857143   28.571429   28.571429
7   1-Aug   john    apple   50.000000   25.000000   25.000000
8   1-Sep   pete    orange  0.000000    0.000000    100.000000
```

new data with added mango:

```py
data = {'date':['1-Jan', '1-Feb', '1-Mar', '1-Apr', '1-May', '1-Jun', '1-July', '1-Aug', '1-Sep'], 'name':['john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'pete'], 'fruit':['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'orange', 'orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

ps. the actual data has multi unique "fruits" and "names". I'm only showing part of it as example.

All help appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {'date': ['1-Jan', '1-Feb', '1-Mar', '1-Apr', '1-May', '1-Jun', '1-July', '1-Aug', '1-Sep'], 'name': ['john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'john', 'pete'], 'fruit': ['apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'orange', 'orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['add'] = (df.groupby(['fruit', 'name']).cumcount() + 1)
df['all'] = (df.groupby('name')['fruit'].cumcount() + 1)
df['apple'] = df['add'].loc[df.fruit == 'apple']
df['mango'] = df['add'].loc[df.fruit == 'mango']
df['orange'] = df['add'].loc[df.fruit == 'orange']
df = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(0))
df['apple_pct'] = (df['apple'] / df['all']) * 100
df['mango_pct'] = (df['mango'] / df['all']) * 100
df['orange_pct'] = (df['orange'] / df['all']) * 100
df = df.drop(['add', 'all', 'apple', 'mango', 'orange'], axis=1).round(2)
```

I rounded the percentages at the end, you can undo it if you want. The result is:

```
    date  name   fruit  apple_pct  mango_pct  orange_pct
0   1-Jan  john   apple     100.00       0.00        0.00
1   1-Feb  john   apple     100.00       0.00        0.00
2   1-Mar  john  orange      66.67       0.00       33.33
3   1-Apr  john   mango      50.00      25.00       25.00
4   1-May  john  orange      40.00      20.00       40.00
5   1-Jun  john  orange      33.33      16.67       50.00
6  1-July  john   apple      42.86      14.29       42.86
7   1-Aug  john   apple      50.00      12.50       37.50
8   1-Sep  pete  orange      00.00      00.00      100.00
```

Comment: thanks Amir! this works and was able to add more variables into the df.